# Where can I find such result?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm interesting in neccesary and sufficient conditions for the equation $$x''+cx'+g(x)=p(t)$$ to have a periodic solution, where $g$ is strictly increasing, $c\neq 0$ and $p$ is continuous and $T$-periodic. Someone told me that what I was looking for: 
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow - \infty} g(x) < \overline{p} <\lim_{x\rightarrow + \infty} g(x) $$ 
is a neccesary and sufficient condition,  where $\overline{p} = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T p(t)\ dt$. But he didn't tell where I could find this result.

Any idea of a book or paper that could be useful for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found really nice works about my question and... I am afraid that teh condition I wrote is both neccessary and sufficient in this case. We've alredy proved it in class using a theorem by Capietto, Mawhin and Zanolin (see https://www.jstor.org/stable/2154076?origin=JSTOR-pdf&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)